# Request for Recommendation of a Handbook of pure Mathematics

Tags: soft-question

I am looking for some books  at  undergrad level that give a good pedagogical coverage of of topics like topology,group theory,analysis,measure theory and probability with a nice exposition.Even books that separately cover only one or some of these topics will do.Please recommend some books of that sort.

Comment: You'll find books that do a good job of covering one of those subjects, and you'll find books that give a *very* broad overview of what all of those subjects are about, but you'll never find a single book from which you can learn all of those subjects.

Answer (score 0):

I always like to recommend ['Introduction to Analysis'](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486650383) by Maxwell Rosenlicht. It's a short read, but It covered everything I needed for my Advanced Calculus (Real Analysis) course. It also came highly recommended by my professor. It also was nice that it was one of the few reasonably priced math books I've seen.